# Python ortools scheduling max/min weekly work hours

Tags: python, scheduling, or-tools

I'm trying to implement a automated scheduling solution using the ortools and have been studying the examples here, https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/master/examples/python/shift_scheduling_sat.py

However I am stuck with having predefined shifts that varied in durations, for example

```py
shifts = [
  { shift_id: 1, duration: 8 },
  { shift_id: 2, duration: 12 },
  ...etc
]
```

How would I express the constraint below as soft constraints

> if selected, the max hours that this nurse can work is 40 and minimum should work is 20.

Comment: what is the meaning of should ? must, can with a penalty ?

Comment: Not a must, it should still be feasible if the constraint is not met completely. Ideally, I am looking for a way to increase the penalty as more shifts are assigned to an employee so that it will get evenly distributed by the hours.  Really appreciate the help Laurent

Comment: Have you read https://github.com/google/or-tools/blob/stable/ortools/sat/doc/channeling.md ?

Comment: I read it and I think I understand how to link a variables together.  However, the example does not cover the situation where i need the to add a constraint comparing two sum of variables.  In my case, if employee is selected, the sum of total work hours preferably does not exceed the limit.